# I've broken debugging in Visual Studio. I think I pressed a wrong key

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't know what I've done. Visual Studio used to stop when it hit an exception and now it just continues and doesn't take me to the offending code.

Does anyone know what I've pressed to turn it off? And how to turn it back on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Debug" "Exceptions" "Break when an exception is"

Comment: I've looked there. I've hit the reset all button, but it's still doing the same thing.